Ubuntu 24.04 with Nvidia driver "libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen"
After updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. (on Wayland) I am unable to open Settings, Nautilus file explorer, etc. When trying to open Nautilus from the Terminal, I get the error libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen. I am using the Nvidia driver 535. When installing the driver 550 (or 545 as well), it is instantly possible to open Nautilus, etc., without any errors. But when I then reboot, the graphics driver isn't loading correctly, and I only get a low resolution, and I'm unable to use external screens on my notebook. Does anyone know a solution to that?
Addition: When switching from Wayland to x11 everything works.

Did you manage to find a solution? My laptop is getting a black screen when I use Wayland, but it works okay under X11. I used Wayland for a couple of years and was quite happy with it... until this sad upgrade :(

Unfortunately, I didn't find any other solution. And I really think that this is very unfortunate, since X11 is becoming more and more outdated and has several security issues. The only suitable display server protocol out there that appears to be available as a replacement nowadays is Wayland. But with all its shortcomings and dependency problems, I'd rather stick with X11 until Wayland becomes the primary DSP for Ubuntu.

One thing you could try out is to boot into recovery mode (console mode with root and networking) and use ubuntu-drivers autoinstall to let Ubuntu automatically install the best driver for your graphics card. That at least fixed the black screen problem for me when trying to use Wayland on Ubuntu 24.04. But it then led to several other issues, as mentioned in my post above. But maybe it could resolve your troubles. Anyway, keep in mind, that the autoinstall option is marked as deprecated. Nevertheless, it still works.

I found the cause of my issue. The error was likely a side effect of the main problem. I noticed that some i915 firmware files were not loading during the update-initramfs process. I copied the files from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915 to /lib/firmware/i915, and now everything works correctly.
I haven't determined why the compressed modules (that are currently in that folder) are not loading, but I have submitted a bug report about this issue.

Thanks I had the same issue and your solution worked. I have reported a bug here:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2067374

How do you "manually copy" the files from the git repository to the firmware folder? I've been trying for a while and don't see the mechanism to copy and paste those files. Cloning and pasting in terminal did not work either and generated an error "repository not found". Any help is appreciated.

@BlackJohnny Lucky you. I have major problems with Xwayland and I wish I could go back to X11. If I configure it to use X11, black screen on boot.

I had the same issue and I can confirm that this:
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-egl-wayland1
worked

I don't know if this is a cure-all, but I had a similar issue with Wayland after upgrading to 24.04 on Wayland, where all gnome programs wouldn't launch and gave that exact error - even down to the driver issue, the fix for me was simply:
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-egl-wayland1
After a reboot all my issues seemed to go. Again, I appreciate this may not be a cure-all.

Doing this install also worked for getting flatpak apps to run under wayland.

Great, worked for me. No reboot was needed.
